# A three-dimensional data structure that holds items in a positional relationship to each other

Tags: java, data-structures

I have an assignment on Data structure, the prof wants us to use different kinds of DS in the project,  but I don't know what he means with **(A three-dimensional data structure that holds items in a positional relationship to each other. Each cell in the data structure can hold multiple items.)**
I tried Arraylists of objects, queues with objects!

any idea what kind of DS I can try to save my time?

thanks

Comment: To preserve positional relationships (the keywords here are spatial subdivision and spatial hashing) have a look at kd-tree, octree and uniform grid.

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to use Guava, then I would consider a [Multimap](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) of `MyObj` indexed by `XyzCoord`, where `XyzCoord` is a custom object to hold three positional numbers, and `MyObj` is the custom object you wish to store one or more of at various coordinates.

Avoiding Guava, you can use a standard `Map` of `List<MyObj>`. It could also be indexed by `List<Integer>` which are of length 3.

The fact is that there are many, many ways to do this. Your question may be a bit too broad as a result. Have a look at the collection classes some more and try to ask specific questions about each one if you don't know how they are used.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest spatial data structure is a 3D array. In java you can create one with as follows:

```
Object[][][] my3DArray = new Object[10][10][10];
```

Here you can store 10*10*10=1000 Object in spatial relation to each other. Unfortunately, there are only 10 possible coordinates in each dimension.

If you want something more efficient, look for quadtrees/octrees, kd-trees (as mentioned by @BeyelerStudios in the comments), R-Trees, LSH (locality sensitive hashing) or even space-filling curves (Z-curve, Hilbert curve, ...). These are just the main families, there are many versions of DSs of each type.

**EDIT** to answer comment.
Except the 3D array approach, all solutions above are quite space efficient. The most space efficient one may be the [PH-Tree](http://www.phtree.org) (a type of quadtree, developed by myself) in some cases it may require less memory than a plain array of coordinates. Unfortunately it is comparatively complex to understand and implement.

If you want to use a 1D sorting scheme, such as array or list, try using a space filling curve. The Z-curve may be easiest.
Using spacefilling curves you can calculate a 'key' (z-key or Morton-number) for each point in space and then sort these in the array or list. In such an ordered list/array, direct neighbors are also likely (but not guaranteed) to be close in 3D space. Inversely, points that are close in 3D space tend (but not guaranteed) to be close in the list/array.

For integer coordinates, the z-key (also called [MortonNumber](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#InterleaveTableObvious)) can be calculated by interleaving the bits of the coordinates. You can also do this for floating points values, but you need to be careful with negative values, otherwise you may get a rift between positive and negative values.

Comment: thanks for your input ! is there a way of doing this with linked lists or queues ?

Comment: because there is a constraint on memory size!